# D3 Force Directed Graph click event not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, d3-force-directed

I'm new to d3.js and JavaScript as well. Here is my code to the force directed graph in d3 with the CSV file data.

Before getting to it, here is the snippet of the code that i want to make the similar http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

Everything about the graph is fine but the onclick event doesn't seem to work.
The click funtion supposed to apply the click event to all the nodes in the csv data (which is 16 nodes) but my graph only has 9 nodes.

I have tried to put the click data to these specific nodes but failed instead. Also here is the CSV data that i want to draw the graph

https://github.com/hohadang1999/Authorship-Network-Graph/blob/master/publications.csv

```
    d3.csv("publications.csv", function(error, links) {
var nodes = {};
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source}); 
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});    

});
var width = 1500,
    height = 500;


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(180)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("stroke","#eee")
    .on("click", click);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);


node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .style("fill","lightcoral")
    .style("stroke","red");


node.append("text")
    .attr("x",20)
    .attr("dy", ".65em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


node.on("click", function )




function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
    });
    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
   return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
function click() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r",6)
        .style("fill", "#ccc");


}



});
```

What i want to achieve is the click event on these nodes as the graph shown

Answer (score 0):

There might be other issues (I didn't run your script), but one problem I can see clearly is the line `"node.on("click", function )` which isn't mapping the click event to the `click()` function you wrote. You should change that to `node.on("click", click)`.